# How do I refer to a create method in a minitest to test the controller?

Tags: unit-testing, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm using Rails 5 and minitest.  How do I refer to a create URL in my test meant to test out the controller's create method?  In my routes file, I have

```
resources :items
```

And in my test file, I have

```
  test "do create" do
    person = people(:one)
    rating = 10
    post items_create_url, params: {person_id: person.id, rating: rating}

    # Verify we got the proper response
    assert_response :success
  end
```

However, the above test is dying with a

```
undefined local variable or method `items_create_url'
```

error.  What's the right way to refer to my create method in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RESTful routes, models are considered to be a collection of things. As you are creating a new item, you are posting a new item (the data) to the collection of existing items, so Rails uses:

```
post items_url, params: {person_id: person.id, rating: rating}
```

For more info on routing, the Rails guides really are the best source of info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html